# Remove words from field using words from a table in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I'm trying to remove words from a field in SAS using a table of words.

I've been able to isolate each word using some code I found online, but I am unable to remove the word from within the field.

For example if the field is:

"The fox jumped over the moon"

if the word "jumped" is in the list of words then the result should look like:

"The fox over the moon"

Here is the table of stopwords to remove:

```
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE BOW.QUERY_FOR_STOPWORDS AS 
   SELECT t1.StopWords
      FROM BOW.STOPWORDS t1;
QUIT;
```

Here is the table with the field that needs to be removed:

```
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.QUERY_FOR_ANNU_COMMENTS AS 
   SELECT t1.Comment
      FROM BOW.ANNU_COMMENTS t1;
QUIT;
```

Comment: just in case if you are looking for dynamic replace.

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/replacing-multiple-characters-in-a-string-dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending off how much words you have other solutions.

```
data _NULL_;
    set STOPWORDS end=e;
    if _N_=1 then call execute('data result;set ANNU_COMMENTS;newComment=Comment;');
    call execute('if _N_=1 then __'||put(_N_,z30.)||'+prxparse("s/'||trimn(StopWords)||'//");');
    call execute('call prxchange(__'||put(_N_,z30.)||',-1,newComment);');   
    if e then call execute('drop __:;run;');
run;
```

This will take stopwords an generate datastep from it than this datastep process comments.

EDIT:
To remove only words by word boundary you have to use \b in the regex.

```
data _NULL_;
    set STOPWORDS end=e;
    if _N_=1 then call execute('data result;set ANNU_COMMENTS;newComment=Comment;');
    call execute('if _N_=1 then __'||put(_N_,z30.)||'+prxparse("s/\b'||trimn(StopWords)||'\b//");');
    call execute('call prxchange(__'||put(_N_,z30.)||',-1,newComment);');   
    if e then call execute('drop __:;run;');
run;
```

Comment: Hello Lee, How can I get this to generate the new field without any of the stopwords and place it next to the comment field as "new comment"

Comment: Simple copy first in new variable than change that. I edited the code to reflect that.

Comment: I am getting the following error: 582       + if _N_=1 then __000000000000000000000000000291+prxparse("s/HERSE"//");"
                                                                             __
                                                                             388
                                                                             76
ERROR 388-185: Expecting an arithmetic operator.

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

Comment: NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
WARNING: The data set WORK.RESULT may be incomplete.  When this step was stopped there were 0 observations and 25 variables.
WARNING: Data set WORK.RESULT was not replaced because this step was stopped.

Comment: That is because your word has an " inside

Comment: It worked with but maybe too well. I have single letters in the word list. Now all letters have been removed. only numbers remain. Is there a way to have only exact matches work per word instead of letters?

Comment: @cartoom02 i added the changed variant

Comment: Thanks so much it worked perfectly only have to clean the extra spaces now, which I have code for.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is `replace()`:

```
SELECT REPLACE(t1.Comment, 'jumped', '')
FROM BOW.ANNU_COMMENTS t1;
```

However, you have a problem with spaces.  If this is an issue and you want complete words, then this might work:

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH ' ' FROM REPLACE(' ' || t1.Comment || ' ', ' jumped ', ''))
FROM BOW.ANNU_COMMENTS t1;
```

Comment: I need to use all the words in the table   SELECT t1.StopWords
      FROM BOW.STOPWORDS  not just the words "jumped"

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use hash iterator, such as:

```
data want;
   if 0 then set STOPWORDS;
   if _n_=1 then do;
      declare hash h(dataset:'STOPWORDS');
      declare hiter iter('h');
      h.definekey('StopWords');
      h.definedata('StopWords');
      h.definedone();
   end;
   set ANNU_COMMENTS;
      rc=iter.first();
      do while(rc=0);
          newComment=ifc(findw(newComment,strip(StopWords))>0,tranwrd(newComment,strip(StopWords),''),newComment);
          rc=iter.next();
      end;
    drop StopWords rc;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

A macro can be written that generates the cleaning data step.

This example blends Shenglin's use of tranwrd with codegen of Lee.

```
%macro flense (
  data=Commments,
  var=Comment, 
  newvar=CommentFlensed, 
  censor=BOW.StopWordsList,
  term=StopWords
);

  proc sql noprint;
    select quote(trim(&term),"'") into :sq_word1-;  * single quote the words to prevent possible macro evaluation later;
    from &censorData;

  data &out;
    set &data;
    &newvar = &var;

    %* for each censored word, generate an if statement
     * that checks if the word (or term) is present, and if so
     * removes the word from the new variable;

    %local i quoted_word;
    %do i = 1 %to &SQLOBS;

      %let quoted_word = &&&sq_word&i;

      if (indexw(&newvar.,&quoted_word)) then 
        &newvar = tranwrd(&newvar,&quoted_word,'');

    %end;
  run;

%mend;

%flense();
```